What happens if you win a diversity visa?
I have applied for a diversity visa and was wondering what would happen if I actually won (big if I know). What is the process?

See Diversity Visa Program - Entry, especially

Step 3 If Selected
Step 4 Confirm Your Qualifications
Step 5 Submit Your Immigrant Visa and Alien Registration Application
Step 6 Prepare Supporting Documents
Step 7 Interview
Step 8 Prepare for the Interview
Step 9 Applicant Interview
Step 10 After the Interview

